# Retrofit with large data payloads

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have an API endpoint that can sometimes return a large payload of data (not images/files) and at times the payload size can cause cause my app to throw `out of memory exception`

this is an example of what my interface looks like

```
@GET("People")
fun getPeopleAsync(): Deferred<Response<List<Person>>>
```

I am curious it using `@Streaming` would work with data payloads? I have only seen it used with files so would this even work with data payloads?

Are there any other methods for dealing with large payloads in retrofit?

Comment: I guess you've used the pagination concept here.

Comment: It could be achieve from APIs calling with sending the specific parameters.
Please try to get data into chunks instead of loading at once.

Comment: @Dipak paging/chunks was what I was thinking of but required changes to the backend api to support that so I didn't know is there was a way to solve this with retrofit without backend changes

Comment: can you share data payload link, for try to solve this issue

Comment: hi please exact data size in heap memory taken . Also can you share screen shot of what you are building using this data I guess there is chance that out of memory is thrown by rendering part and not the data part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common pattern to fetch large lists, as mentioned in the comments, is to use pagination. So you will need to [implement the pagination in the Server](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/pagination-in-the-rest-api/) first.

The call will be something like this:

```
@GET("People")
fun getPeopleAsync(pageIndex: Int, pageSize: Int = 10): Deferred<Response<List<Person>>>
```

And you need to [detect when the RecyclerView reaches the bottom](https://medium.com/@ayhamorfali/android-detect-when-the-recyclerview-reaches-the-bottom-43f810430e1e) to call the API again with the next page index, and in the meanwhile show a progress bar or loading view in the screen until the response is received